# initialization of ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: arrays, c, struct, initialization, compound-literals

I'm trying to anonymously create a struct using a couple variables and gcc, given the flag `-Werror`, won't compile the following:

```
char file_name[A1FS_NAME_MAX];
strcpy(file_name, strrchr(path, '/') + 1);
a1fs_dentry *new_dentry_ptr = (a1fs_dentry *) fs->data_table + last_extent->start * A1FS_BLOCK_SIZE + remaining_directory_entries * sizeof(a1fs_dentry);
*new_dentry_ptr = (a1fs_dentry) {
    .ino = (a1fs_ino_t) fs->first_free_inode_i,
    .name = file_name
};
```

where `a1fs_dentry` is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct a1fs_dentry {
    /** Inode number. */
    a1fs_ino_t ino;

    /** File name. A null-terminated string. */
    char name[A1FS_NAME_MAX];

} a1fs_dentry;
```

The warning causing it to fail is at `.name = file_name`. It also says `error: missing braces around initializer`. I tried casting file_name to a char array but it doesn't like that. My goal is to get it to where it doesn't give those warnings anymore.

Comment: You'd probably need to initialize with an empty/zero name, then strcpy into it instead of trying to assign the stack-allocated file_name into it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This initialization of the compound literal in the statement below is invalid

```
*new_dentry_ptr = (a1fs_dentry) {
    .ino = (a1fs_ino_t) fs->first_free_inode_i,
    .name = file_name
};
```

You may not initialize the character array `name` with the expression `file_name` that is implicitly converted to a pointer when used as an initializer,

So instead of using the compound literal you should explicitly assign values to data members of the object pointed to by the pointer `new_dentry_ptr` and for the data member `name` use the standard string function `strcpy` as for example

```
strcpy( new_dentry_ptr->name, file_name );
```